# Breaking down a dictionary list returned from API call

Tags: python, list, dictionary

A recent update to our Zabbix environment has broken some previous scripting written by someone way more advanced than I am and I'm currently stuck trying to work with the returned value.

I start with a simple enough API call that returns the following dict:

```
webscenario = {
    u'httptestid': u'254', 
    u'steps': [
      {
        u'query_fields': [],
        u'name': u'GET Alert',
        u'no': u'1',
        u'url': u'http://{HOST.DNS}/{API}',
        u'follow_redirects': u'1',
        u'variables': []
        u'required': u'aries',
        u'posts': u'', 
        u'retrieve_mode': u'0', 
        u'httpstepid': u'700', 
        u'headers': [], 
        u'post_type': u'0', 
        u'timeout': u'15s', 
        u'status_codes': u'200',
        u'httptestid': u'254'
      }
    ], 
    u'name': u'Alerts API',
    u'headers': [
      {
        u'name': u'Content-Type', 
        u'value': u'application/json'
      }
    ]
}
```

The objective is to rebuild the headers for an automated update push using data returned in the above API call.

```
headers_dict = dict()
headers = webscenario.get("headers")

for h in str(headers).splitlines():
    headers_dict.update({h.split(':')[1].strip(): h.split(':')[1].strip())})
print headers_dict
```

Initially, this was written as `headers.splitlines()` and that started throwing some errors (like `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`). Some googling around and it seemed that adding the string identifier solved that exception. But now I'm running into formatting problems for the header and I'm totally stuck.

The output I'm getting for headers is list dictionary (dictionary list?):

```
<type 'list'>: [{u'name': u'Content-Type', u'value': u'application/json'}]
```

What I need to do is build a dictionary that is the following:

```
{Content-Type: application/json}
```

Unicode notation aside, I can work on that "problem" (if it is even one) once I can get it down to what I need.

Comment: There are multiple levels to the data in `webscenario`.  Can you provide expected output for the entire `webscenario` content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that

```
formatted_headers = dict()
headers = webscenario.get("headers")

for header in headers:
    formatted_headers[header['name']] = header['value']
```

Is enough for what you need to achieve, right ?

Comment: or even `formatted_headers = {header['name']: header['value'] for header in webscenario['headers']}`

Comment: Yep, sure. But I often don't suggest list/dict comprehension at first for beginners, they often find them not clear enough!

Comment: Yes! That works sufficiently in this scenario (and probably most of the current scenarios I need this for).

However, could you aim me at how I would do this in a more generic factor in which the potential for multiple returned results for the header dictionary list (think authentication details as well).

Comment: And after further review, it seems this is my solution. Thank you!